# Using Java Dates, Given a year, I want a method that should return a list of dates representing a given day of the week, all 52 times

Tags: java, date

A method receives and integer representing a year and an integer representing a day of the week. The method should return a list of dates representing a given day of the week. For example, if the year is 2014 and the day of week is 2 then the method should return a list of dates representing all the Mondays in 2014.

```
public List<Date> getDatesforDayOfWeek(int year, int dayOfWeek) throws InvalidDateException
```

I'm not too sure what the best code would be. Any suggestions?

```
if (year <= 0) {
    throw new InvalidDateException("Invalid year.");
}
if ((dayOfWeek < 1) || (dayOfWeek > 7)) {
    throw new InvalidDateException("Invalid day.");
}
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss z yyyy");
```

Comment: What do you mean when you say 'best code'? And what have you tried?

Comment: `Calendar` would be my first stop, but if you're using Java 8, you could also look at the new Time API or even `JodaTime` if you can use 3rd party APIs

Answer (score 0):

Check this implementation that would work for non-leap years (and for leap years with some modification)

```
public List<Date> getDatesforDayOfWeek(int year, int dayOfWeek)
            throws InvalidDateException {

        if (year <= 0) {
            throw new InvalidDateException("Invalid year.");
        }
        if ((dayOfWeek < 1) || (dayOfWeek > 7)) {
            throw new InvalidDateException("Invalid day.");
        }

        List<Date> dates = new ArrayList<Date>();

        // Start with the given inputs
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        cal.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
        cal.set(Calendar.MONTH, Calendar.JANUARY);
        int day = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);
        while (day != dayOfWeek) {
            cal.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
            day = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);
        }

        // Make this 366 for a leap year
        for (int i = 0; i < 365; i += 7) {
            if (cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK) == dayOfWeek
                    && cal.get(Calendar.YEAR) == year) {
                dates.add(cal.getTime());
                cal.add(Calendar.DATE, 7);
            }
        }

        return dates;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InvalidDateException {
        for (Date date : new DateList().getDatesforDayOfWeek(2014, 4)) {
            System.out.println(date);
        }

    }

}

class InvalidDateException extends Exception {

    public InvalidDateException(String string) {
        super(string);
    }

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

}
```

Comment: Seems wasteful to go over each day when you know there is a fixed space between each interested day. I know its small, but your for loop should really have a += 7.

Comment: Follow up question: How can I make the list print every thing on it's own line?

Comment: This will print everything on one line.

Comment: Is there a way to make every instance of a Monday to print on its own line? >:D

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question, I would use a [`Calendar`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html) to solve this problem (actually I'd first pick [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/), but otherwise Calendar because there are a lot of corner cases to handle) -

```
public static List<Date> getDatesforDayOfWeek(int year, int dayOfWeek) {
  List<Date> al = new ArrayList<>();
  if (dayOfWeek >= 1 && dayOfWeek <= 7) {
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
    cal.set(Calendar.MONTH, Calendar.JANUARY);
    cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);

    while (cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK) != dayOfWeek) {
      cal.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < 52; i++) {
      al.add(cal.getTime());
      cal.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 7);
    }
  }
  return al;
```

}

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  System.out.println(getDatesforDayOfWeek(2014, 2));
}
```

Output is (formatted, and 50 lines omitted, for display)

```
[Mon Jan 06 23:52:16 EST 2014, 
...     
Mon Dec 29 23:52:16 EST 2014]
```

Comment: This gives only the first occurrence of the day in a month. The OP needs all occurrences (52 or 53) in the year.

Answer (score 0):

Looking through all the answers they will provide you what you're looking for. Here is another approach I believe to be a little more efficient then the previous answers.

```
public static List<Date> GetDatesForDayOfWeek(int year, int dayOfWeek)
{

        // Days in the week
        final int DAYS_IN_WEEK = 7;

        List<Date> dates = new ArrayList<Date>();

        Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        c.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
        c.set(Calendar.MONTH, 0);                   // January
        c.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);            // The first

        // Find the first day we are interested in
        int offset = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);
        if(offset!= dayOfWeek)
        {
            c.add(Calendar.DATE, (dayOfWeek < offset ? (offset + 7) % 7 : (dayOfWeek - offset)));
        }


        while(c.get(Calendar.YEAR) == year)
        {
            dates.add(c.getTime());
            c.add(Calendar.DATE, DAYS_IN_WEEK);
        }

        return dates;

    }



public static void main(String[] args){

    System.out.println("A list of all Sundays in 2014.");
    List<Date> days = GetDatesForDayOfWeek(2014, Calendar.SUNDAY);
    for(Date ad : days){
        System.out.println(ad);
    }
}
```

Running the above would give you every sunday in 2014 with the output of.

```
    A list of all Sundays in 2014.
    Sun Jan 05 23:49:56 EST 2014
   ...
    Sun Dec 28 23:49:56 EST 2014
```

Answer (score 0):

New Java8 DateTime API gives very clean methods to use for any Date, Time related code.
Below is my part on your query.

```
public class ExampleDayOfYear {
public static void main(String[] args) throws InvalidDateException {
 List<LocalDate> list=getDatesforDayOfWeek(2020,2);
list.forEach(System.out::println);
    System.out.println("Total dates: "+list.size());
}

public static String getDay(int day, int month, int year) {
           LocalDate dt=LocalDate.of(year,month,day);
  return dt.getDayOfWeek().toString();
}

private static int getDayOfYear(int year){
LocalDate dt = LocalDate.parse(year+"-01-01");
return dt.getDayOfWeek().getValue();
}

public static List<LocalDate> getDatesforDayOfWeek(int year, int dayOfWeek) throws 
InvalidDateException{
    List<LocalDate> list=new ArrayList<LocalDate>();
    int differenceOfdaysToDayofWeek=0;
    int firstDayOfYear= getDayOfYear(year); // Wednesday
int count=1;
```

// This method call gives the date of first Monday. Also, this method requires the differenceOfDate which we have found out from getDaysDifference.

```
LocalDate firstDateOfWeek=getFirstDateOfWeek(year,getDaysDifference(firstDayOfYear));
    list.add(firstDateOfWeek);
    while(firstDateOfWeek.getYear()== year){
        firstDateOfWeek=  getDateWeekWise(firstDateOfWeek);
        if(firstDateOfWeek.getYear()==year){
                 count++;

      list.add(firstDateOfWeek);  }
        }

 return list;
}
```

// First Day is Wednesday, so we need ot get first date of the January, 2020.

```
    private static int getDaysDifference(int firstDayOfYear){
    int difDays=0;
    int dayofWeekNum=Integer.valueOf(DayOfWeek.MONDAY.ordinal()+1);
```

// It gives the int value of DayOfWeek. e.g. if it's Monday it will give 0 because week ordinal value starts from 0.

```
    if(firstDayOfYear==dayofWeekNum) {
       }if(firstDayOfYear>dayofWeekNum){
    difDays= dayofWeekNum+7 -firstDayOfYear;
}if(firstDayOfYear<dayofWeekNum)
{
    difDays= dayofWeekNum -firstDayOfYear;
}
return difDays;
}
private static LocalDate getFirstDateOfWeek(int year,int differenceOfWeekDays){
    LocalDate dt = LocalDate.of(year,01,01).plusDays(differenceOfWeekDays);
          return dt;
}

private static LocalDate getDateWeekWise(LocalDate dt){
    dt=dt.plusWeeks(1);
return dt;
}
}
class InvalidDateException extends Exception{
InvalidDateException(String s){
    super(s);
}
}
```